# android - onStart and onStop called in weird places

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm getting this very weird log when starting a new activity, and I can't seem to find anything to explain this behavior (my notes are after the hyphen):

```
D/LifeCycle﹕ onStart - old activity - first activity started for the first time
...
D/LifeCycle﹕ starting new activity  - a button triggers starting the second activity
D/LifeCycle﹕ onStart - old activity - ??????
D/LifeCycle﹕ onStart - new activity - second activity is starting
D/LifeCycle﹕ onStop - old activity  - first activity is stopped
...
D/LifeCycle﹕ onStart - old activity - pressing the back button, returning to the first activity
D/LifeCycle﹕ onStop - old activity  - ??????
D/LifeCycle﹕ onStop - new activity  - second activity is stopped
```

This is how I start the new activity (I don't have to pass anything):

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ResultListActivity.class));
```

In addition, when I call `findViewById` in the question marked functions, I get null.
Can anyone explain why I'm getting this log?

BTW, I'm running on an emulator, but when I ran it on my nexus 5 it seemed to behave the same.

Comment: @Talor can you post how you are handling the button click? It'd be good to understand what's happening there and how you are starting the new activity. It might be weird, it might be not

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I added the code for starting the new activity.

Comment: @Talor, is `ResultListActivity` extending any other class by any chance? Have you got any base activity defined?

Comment: WOW, you're right, I extended the wrong activity by mistake....
THANK YOU VERY MUCH! :)